# Как получить значения всех выбранных checkbox'ов?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не знаю как получить значения выбранных checkbox'ов. ***Пример***:

```js
$('.listAdditional input:checkbox').change(function() {
  var favorite = [];
  //some active here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listAdditional">

  <div class="part1">
    <h3>Состояние</h3>
    <input name="additional" id="i1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="i1">Новый</label>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input name="additional" id="i2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="i2">Как новый</label>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input name="additional" id="i3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="i3">Б/у</label>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input name="additional" id="i4" type="checkbox">
    <label for="i4">Показывать с фотографиями</label>

    <br>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div class="part2">
    <h3>Наличие</h3>

    <input name="additional" id="i5" type="checkbox">
    <label for="i5">В наличии</label>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input name="additional" id="i6" type="checkbox">
    <label for="i6">Под заказ</label>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input name="additional" id="i7" type="checkbox">
    <label for="i7">В архиве</label>

    <br>
    <br>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  $('.listAdditional input:checkbox').change(function(){
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[name='additional']:checked"), function(){
      favorite.push($(this).next('label').text());
    });
    alert("Value of Selected Checkboxes: " + favorite.join(", "));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listAdditional">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="part1">
                                    <h3>Состояние</h3>
                                    <input name="additional" id="i1" type="checkbox">
                                    <label for="i1">Новый</label>

                                    <br>
                                    <br>

                                    <input name="additional" id="i2" type="checkbox">
                                    <label for="i2">Как новый</label>

                                    <br>
                                    <br>

                                    <input name="additional" id="i3" type="checkbox">
                                    <label for="i3">Б/у</label>

                                    <br>
                                    <br>

                                    <input name="additional" id="i4" type="checkbox">
                                    <label for="i4">Показывать с фотографиями</label>

                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                </div>

                                <div class="part2">
                                    <h3>Наличие</h3>

                                    <input name="additional" id="i5" type="checkbox">
                                    <label for="i5">В наличии</label>

                                    <br>
                                    <br>

                                    <input name="additional" id="i6" type="checkbox">
                                    <label for="i6">Под заказ</label>

                                    <br>
                                    <br>

                                    <input name="additional" id="i7" type="checkbox">
                                    <label for="i7">В архиве</label>

                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо)

Comment: @NikitaSmith рад стараться

Answer (score -1):

Наверно правильнее было б в input прописать атрибут value со значением

```
<input name="additional" id="i3" type="checkbox" value="Новый">
```

тогда далее попроще их доставать:

```
var values = $('.listAdditional input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
                  .serializeArray()
                  .map(function(item){
                      return item.value;
                  }).join(', ');
```